# How can i dropdown a Menu or anything on Opera Mini without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway where we can dropdown a menu or anything without reloading page on Opera Mini? I know how to dropdown a menu by reloading page with :target CSS but i am looking for a solution where page doesn't reload. I have seen certain websites do that.

At times, I feel Opera Mini is the new IE8. I am looking not to use any libraries like jquery and have zero dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you can't do it with JavaScript, given that the [JavaScript doesn't run on the device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini#JavaScript_support), it runs on the Opera Mini server.

There's the old CSS checkbox trick, though; it's relatively basic, but that doesn't mean Opera Mini may not mess it up anyway. The way it works is you have a label connected to a hidden checkbox. Clicking the label toggles the checkbox. You use an adjacent sibling combinator and the `:checked` pseudo-class to show another element only when the checkbox is checked:

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* hide the checkbox */
.hidden-cb {
  display: none;
}
/* By default, this is not shown */
.show-on-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
/* But if it's immediately after a checked checkbox, we show it */
input:checked + .show-on-checkbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="hidden-cb">Click me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="hidden-cb" class="hidden-cb">
<div class="show-on-checkbox" id="target">Hey, here I am!</div>
```

It doesn't have to be just a simple appear/disappear thing, you can do anything CSS allows that Opera Mini supports.

I was about to suggest the `:hover` trick as an alternative, but on Opera Mini, 99% of your users will be using their fingers...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have already tried Checkbox method and unfortunately that doesn't work too. Checkbox is not supported by Opera Mini. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: @AwesomeHat: Surely Opera Mini supports checkboxes, but I guess it doesn't support some other aspect of the above (`:checked` perhaps, or the adjacent sibling combinator). Though I find that slightly surprising, neither of those is particularly new or demanding on the UA... I think if something as simple as that doesn't work, you're not likely to have much luck. :-| (I was about to suggest the `:hover` trick, but these are phones...)